# WooSlider maximum height

Tags: css, wordpress, slider

I am using WooSlider to display a gallery for each project of mine. Many of my projects are in HD aspect ratio (1280x720) while other older ones are SD (720x540).

The problem I am having is that I would like to make my site width 1280px wide but since WooSlider sets it's size according to the website width, the SD images would be enormous in vertical height (around 960px). The HD images look fine since they remain at 1280x720px.

Since I cannot restrict the width of the slider as 1280 works great for HD images, I thought perhaps it's possible to restrict the height of the slider so that it will crop the gigantic SD images. Cropping would be ok so long as the SD images stay centered within the crop. But I would need the slider to remain responsive so a fixed height won't do.

So is this possible? To restrict the maximum height of WooSlider, while still allowing it to be responsive?

Alternately, if I could check the width of the slider images, I could possibly restrict the height only when images are in SD format, while leaving the HD ones unaffected.

Here is an example of my website at 1024px wide, displaying SD images. As you can see, even at 1024px, the vertical height of the scaled SD images in the slider is very large so at 1280px it would be enormous:

http://richardrosenman.com/portfolio-items/kraft-dinner-pimp-my-ride/

Any suggestions or info welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What does it have to do with php? For me you should just add `max-height` attribute to `wooslider` class in CSS.

Comment: I've tried that but for some reason it's not working for me. It seems to limit the WooSlider viewport height but the slide images themselves override it and display back at normal (enlarged) size. (I have removed the PHP tag).